# How to close all jquery ui dialog before open a new dialog?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

I want to close all jquery dialogs before open a new dialog.

I'm trying with following code.

```
$(".ui-dialog-content").dialog("close");
```

It works but it too close new dialog too.

please help me anyone.

Comment: why don't you call this statement before calling the opening code of the new dialog?

Comment: I called it before call the new window. But it close new window too,this is only my problem

Comment: Do you have any details on the dialog being opened? You could use the css `:not()` selector.

Comment: sorry it works,but new dialog goes to bottom.

Answer (score 10):

Try:

```
$(".ui-dialog-content").not(<selector for the dialog you don't want to close>).dialog("close");
```

Answer (score 4):

Just ran into this myself. I solved it like this. `.dialog` is a class that all the elements I made into dialogs share.

```
$(".ui-dialog:visible").find(".dialog").dialog("close");
```

Comment: This seems like the best solution to me - it is necessary NOT to close the non-visible jQuery dialogs, because these may not have yet been initialized (which results in an error in my case).

Answer (score 1):

Following on from Chris's solution, you can do the same without adding your own custom class with:

```
$(".ui-dialog:visible").find(".ui-dialog-content").dialog("close");
```

Answer (score 0):

How are you opening the new Dialog? You must be opening each dialog using it's own code, e.g.

```
$('#dialog1').dialog();
$('#dialog2').dialog();
```

etc... in order to open each individually?

Just give them all a class name `class="opened-dialogs"` then call `$('.opened-dialogs').dialog("close");` before then opening the new one.