# Close all open dialog boxes? (JQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

How can I close all opened `dialog` boxes in `jQuery`?
The situation is next: I have a simple page without dialogs. It has some buttons what open it owns dialogs.

When I click on a button I need to close all opened dialogs.

Here is the HTML:

```
<div id="buttons">
    <a href="#" id="btn_1">Button 1</a>
    <a href="#" id="btn_2">Button 2</a>
    <a href="#" id="btn_3">Button 3</a>
</div>
<div id="dialog_1" class="dialogbox">...</div>
<div id="dialog_2" class="dialogbox">...</div>
<div id="dialog_3" class="dialogbox">...</div>
```

And here is the jQuery:

```
$(function() {
    $('#buttons').find('a').click(function() {
        // close all dialogs
        $('.dialogbox').dialog("close");

        // find out clicked id and open dialog
        var nr = this.id.split("_")[1];
        $('#dialog_'+nr).dialog();
    });
});
```

The Chrome say: `Uncaught Error: cannot call methods on dialog prior initialization; attempted to call method 'close'`.

I was tried to check `$('.dialogbox').dialog('isOpen')`, but same result.

How can I close all dialogs?

Comment: You must first initialize your dialogs before this function ever get's called  $().ready(function() {$('.dialogbox').dialog({})})

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Since they all inherit the same class, this is the best way to select all and close by:

`$(".ui-dialog-content").dialog("close");`

Comment: Careful!  For dialogs in the HTML that have not yet been initialized, this can result in an error.  A working solution is here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9060927/368896

Answer (score 1):

You can simple try this as they all have the `.ui-dialog-content` class, so select by that and close them, like this:-

```
 $(".ui-dialog-content").dialog("close");
```