# Close all dialog/popup

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-mobile

I have several form/choices which lead to open dialog/popup with jQuery ui in one line. At the end of the chain, I would like to close all the previous ones. My url looks like this : mysite&ui-state=dialog&ui-state=dialog&ui-state=dialog. I can close the last one but not the others... 
I would like to close all of them with this kind of code :

```
$(".ui-dialog-content").dialog("close");
```

To close the last one I use id of the div in which it is contained but how to reach the previous ones ?

**EDIT**

The class are : `ui-page ui-body-c ui-dialog ui-overlay-a` or `ui-page ui-body-c ui-dialog ui-overlay-a ui-page-active`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Close all open dialog boxes? (JQuery)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13587159/close-all-open-dialog-boxes-jquery)

Comment: Already found this one (it's my quote) but it doesn't work for me...

Comment: Possible link to demo or maybe more code ?

Comment: Once you leave a dialog, it get closed. What do you want to achieve?

Comment: Once I leave a dialog to another, the previous one stay open. To quit I have to close them one by one to return to my initial page (without refresh)

Comment: try `$(document).on("pagebeforechange", "[data-role=dialog]", function () { $("[data-role=dialog]").dialog("close"); });` and try `pagebeforeshow` as well.

Comment: Nothing... Same when I try $(".ui-dialog-content").dialog("close"); no error but nothing happens. when I use "pagebeforeshow" I close the last one and all the others ones close themselves on their own but I cannot reopen one...